# using paypal as dealer between two customer in my website

Tags: paypal

I have a website uses paypal to sale X thing at the website itself.
I know how to use paypal to make customer1 buy X1 and also to make customer2 buy another X2.(now moeny in my account)
my qusestion is..Is there a way to make paypal manage selling operation between customer1 to SELL X1 to customer2.(customer2 pay for customer1)??

should I code this by myself or there is a reliable method to do it..thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the Paypal button form code, use the hidden input field "business" and the hidden input field "notify_url". In the "business" field you programatically enter the merchant id from customer1 and in the "notify_url" field you enter the URL of a script on your site that will register the sale.